# What's wrong with this sentence, and how can I write it correctly?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, polarity-items

I need to identify the mistake in the following sentence:

> I don't like football and so does Michael.

What's wrong with this sentence. And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong is that the sense (positive, negative) does not match.

The clause "so does Michael" means he **does** like football - so the joining word "and" is incorrect.

The correction depends on what is to be the correct meaning, either:

1. You both do not like football.

   > I don't like football and neither does Michael.
2. Or you don't like football but Michael does.

   > I don't like football but Michael does.

If I heard this I would probably assume the first correction is what is meant.
However, the sentence is incorrect so its meaning is unclear.

Answer (score -3):

Two different conjunctions are used unnecessarily which creates ambiguity. you can write ..

> I don't like football so does Micheal

or

> Neither I like football nor Micheal

or

> Micheal likes football but not I.

Comment: The first of these is wholly ungrammatical and can't be used in English at all. The second might perhaps be useful within a complicated poem using rather archaic language, but is otherwise completely unsuitable as well. Only the third is any good normally, and it's a little funky — "but I don't" would be more common in this kind of relatively informal situation.